# Present continuous tense (Error)

Tags: present-continuous

"He is knowing him for ten years".

Is the above-mentioned sentence wrong, if yes. Why? Please correct this sentence.

Regards

Comment: In general, please try to provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) like where you found your examples and why you think they might be wrong or right.

Comment: Thanks Max, I'll definitely add more details with examples in my future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present continuous tense is not applicable here, because "to know" is a **stative verb**, which describes a state somebody is in, not a verb that you can catch someone in the process of doing, like "crying" or "dying" (**action verbs**). (Further types of verbs here: http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/action-verbs/)

You would have to say "He has known him for ten years." Because the ten years started at some time in the past and is extending into the present, this is called the `present perfect`.

http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html explains the present continuous more deeply.